# Visualizing resource dependencies and relationships underlying EPSG CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, epsg, datum

I'll go straight to the point; I remember long ago that I was quite shocked the first time I discovered that [`EPSG:4326`](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html) was kind of an "umbrella" definition on top of *many* others, which often stay hidden unless you specifically need them (which is almost never the case except if you are a geodesist).

Is there a tool to visually represent and explore all the underlying EPSG resources, their relationships and the structure binding them, which altogether make up any of the most well-known CRS, such as the [`ESPG:4326`](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html)?

The result I'm looking for should look like what you see in this picture: https://tomroth.com.au/epsg/Capture-12.png

Some kind of visual equivalent for the great tool [`projinfo`](https://proj.org/apps/projinfo.html).

It's for pedagogic purposes.

Comment: WGS84 isn't an "umbrella", just a geographic coordinate system. All projected CS have to be defined with respect to a GCS.

Comment: You're right, why the double quotes. What I meant it's that is, indeed, build "on top" of other definitions.

Comment: It's not above, but below, in the context of building blocks, though it's sometimes represented as parallel to PCS, below a generic coordinate reference type which points to both, as in this Esri Projection Engine [entity-relationship diagram](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/concepts/geometry/coordref/coordsys/pe/erd.htm), which was modeled on EPSG. The significance of the GCS is not  restricted to geodesists, since any attempt at reprojection must contend with the potential need for datum transformation.

Comment: @Vince, data model has changed and 4326 is now considered to be a "datum ensemble" via datum:6326.. Or as David B (inside joke) calls it a "dump bucket." All of the WGS 84 realizations are included in this datum ensemble and it has a reduced accuracy.